# sum of binomial coefficient $\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{m-1}{2}}\binom{m}{i}(q-1)^i$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

I do not know how to calculate or simplify this formula. Whether the result can be expanded does not come in the form of binomials or summation symbols. Any help in evaluating this sum would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What if $m$ is even? Do you floor the upper limit of summation?

Comment: I'm sorry for the incorrect expression just now. q is a positive integer and m is odd~@ParclyTaxel

Comment: This looks like a Gaussian hypergeometric function